# Why does HashMap auto-sort character-type keys, though being an unordered collection?

Tags: java, hashmap

I created a small code example in order to demonstrate the difference of HashMap and TreeMap.

```
public class HashMapSimpleValueAutosort {

    private static final char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        inverseAbc(map, "HashMap");

        map = new TreeMap<>();

        inverseAbc(map, "TreeMap");
    }

    private static void inverseAbc(Map<Character, Integer> map, String desc ) {

        System.out.println(desc);

        for (int i=25; i>=0; --i) {
            map.put(alphabet[i], 26 - i);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

What it does, is to assign the alphabet letters in the reverse order inside the map as keys and their position in the alphabet as the corresponding value, using a HashMap and a TreeMap approach.

Althought the keys are inserted in the inversed order, HashMap toString() outputs them in ascending order, just like TreeMap does.

So the question that arises here is:

Does toString() method of HashMap, sorts the keys internally before returning the string represention of the map ?

**EDIT**:

It seams that this might be a JDK or IDE based symptom and not restricted only to toString().

```
public class HashMapSimpleValueAutosort {

    private static final char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        printEntries(map, "HashMap");

        map = new TreeMap<>();

        printEntries(map, "TreeMap");
    }


    private static void printEntries(Map<Character, Integer> map, String desc) {

        System.out.println(desc);

        for (int i=25; i>=0; --i) {
            map.put(alphabet[i], 26 - i);
        }

        System.out.print("{ ");
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%c=%d,", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(" }");
    }

}
```

In the example above I print the key-value pairs as entries.

Comment: Use the source, Luke!

Comment: The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.toString%28%29) does not show that behavior.

Comment: It is very very unlikely that the toString() method sorts this.  Most likely the keys are sorted on insertion (insertion sort) and the toString() method just prints out the keys in the order they are stored in

Comment: But it is known that HashMap does not short the keys. How do they get sorted ?

Comment: Running your code, I get `HashMap
{n=13, s=8, g=20, e=22, q=10, a=26, l=15, u=6, v=5, b=25, o=12, t=7, p=11, y=2, z=1, x=3, m=14, h=19, w=4, i=18, c=24, j=17, k=16, d=23, f=21, r=9}` :: `TreeMap
{a=26, b=25, c=24, d=23, e=22, f=21, g=20, h=19, i=18, j=17, k=16, l=15, m=14, n=13, o=12, p=11, q=10, r=9, s=8, t=7, u=6, v=5, w=4, x=3, y=2, z=1}` - I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I see what OP sees. I'm on 1.8.0_51. Which version are you on?

Comment: Maybe it is a per JVM implementation and version that automatically sorts those simple values. My source was compiled inside Netbeans 8.1 using JDK 1.8.0_65.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It will not, I also cannot reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a curious result of the implementation of `HashMap`.

A `HashMap` has to decide in which of the hash buckets to place the entry. It decides this based on the `hashCode()` of the key object. Now, `hashCode()` can be any integer at all. So it first does this to the hash code:

```
(h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16)
```

Now, your key in this case is of type `Character`. The `hashCode` for `Character` is the value of the character itself. Java `char` is 16-bits wide. So shifting it 16 bits to the right will give you zero. Xoring it with that zero gives you the original value - the `char` value!

The values you have chosen are consecutive. This means that they will happen to be stored in the hash table buckets at indexes i, i+1, i+2...

This also happens to be the order at which the entry set iterator, on which `toString` is based, traverses that table: it goes through the table consecutively. So as long as you don't have collisions, for `Character` keys that happen to be consecutive, you'll see the result "sorted".

Answer (score 1):

It is coincidence that `HashMap` appears sorted, which only occurs because the values are very simple.

If you change to `String`, and double the letters, such that `hashCode()` returns more complex values, the `HashMap` will appear more like what is usually expected: Order appears random (it's isn't, but might as well be).

```
private static final String[] alphabet = {"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk","ll","mm",
                                          "nn","oo","pp","qq","rr","ss","tt","uu","vv","ww","xx","yy","zz"};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    inverseAbc(map, "HashMap");
    map = new TreeMap<>();
    inverseAbc(map, "TreeMap");
}
private static void inverseAbc(Map<String, Integer> map, String desc ) {
    System.out.println(desc);
    for (int i=alphabet.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        map.put(alphabet[i], alphabet.length - i);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

*Output*

```
HashMap
{tt=7, zz=1, xx=3, vv=5, rr=9, pp=11, nn=13, ll=15, jj=17, hh=19, ff=21, dd=23, bb=25, ss=8, yy=2, ww=4, uu=6, qq=10, oo=12, mm=14, kk=16, ii=18, gg=20, ee=22, cc=24, aa=26}
TreeMap
{aa=26, bb=25, cc=24, dd=23, ee=22, ff=21, gg=20, hh=19, ii=18, jj=17, kk=16, ll=15, mm=14, nn=13, oo=12, pp=11, qq=10, rr=9, ss=8, tt=7, uu=6, vv=5, ww=4, xx=3, yy=2, zz=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost -

- **HashMap is not ordered collection**.
- **TreeMap is ordered collection.**

So, if you are expecting that you will put values in certain order in your `HashMap` and it will remain so then it is wrong. It is unordered collection. Also, I ran it my local and `HashMap` output was unordered and `TreeMap` was ordered

Like said above, `TreeMap` is an ordered collection and it works because when you put values in `TreeMap` then a `Comparator` is sorting them. See below `TreeMap.put` implementation.

While when you put values in `HashMap` then there is no such sorting.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> t = root;
    if (t == null) {
        compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

        root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
        size = 1;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
    int cmp;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    // split comparator and comparable paths
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
    if (cpr != null) {
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
    }
    else {
        if (key == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
    }
    Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(key, value, parent);
    if (cmp < 0)
        parent.left = e;
    else
        parent.right = e;
    fixAfterInsertion(e);
    size++;
    modCount++;
    return null;
}
```

---

**Pre-Java8 v/s Java8:**

Implementation of `put` method of `HashMap` in Java8 is different than Java7 or before, and it internally uses `TreeNode` and all, and is logic looks pretty different ... That could be the reason. Check Java8 `HashMap.put` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I am not inserting them in a TreeMap, but in a HashMap first. Then I create a TreeMap for demonstration purposes to show the difference if any.

Comment: @pgmank No buddy, `HashMap` output will be unordered and `TreeMap` will be ordered.

Comment: @hagrawai I know about HashMaps and TreeMaps, but it seems that in my environment, simple values like characters get auto-sorted in the HashMap.

Comment: @pgmank Yes, you are right buddy. Java8 looks like have very different `put` implementation of `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap are the three most popular Map types.

- LinkedHashMap maintains insertion order i.e elements are stored as they are inserted.
- TreeMap stores the elements according to supplied Comparator or in the natural order, if you don’t supply any Comparator.
- HashMap doesn’t guarantee any order.

So if you want the map to retain the insertion order, use **LinkedHashMap**

```
class Solution {
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    char ch ;
    Map<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>() ; 
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        ch = s.charAt(i) ;
        map.put(ch,map.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1) ;
    }
    for(char key : map.keySet())
    {
        if(map.get(key) == 1)
            return s.indexOf(key+"") ; 
    }
    return -1 ; 
}}
```